# how to store multiple values of checkbox values in viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is the code for my viewstate. but it's only store one value.what i need is it will keep the selected multiple values in the checkbox. this method is to keep/hold the value of check box in gridview of paging situation.

```
public void chkAssignee_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        CheckBox selectBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)selectBox.Parent.Parent;  // the row
        GridView myGrid = (GridView)myRow.Parent.Parent; // the gridview
        string ID = myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridViewRow rowSelect = (GridViewRow)selectBox.Parent.Parent;

        int a = rowSelect.RowIndex;

        ViewState["id"] = ID;
        }
```

Comment: try saving it to comma separated string or something.

Comment: Save the contents in a `List` or `Dictionary` and save that in the `ViewState`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following 
Following Code may help u.

```
public void chkAssignee_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox selectBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)selectBox.Parent.Parent;  // the row
        GridView myGrid = (GridView)myRow.Parent.Parent; // the gridview
        string ID = myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridViewRow rowSelect = (GridViewRow)selectBox.Parent.Parent;
```

```
    int a = rowSelect.RowIndex;
    ArrayList SelecterdRowIndices=new ArrayList();
    if(ViewState["SelectedRowIndices"]!=null)
    {
        SelecterdRowIndices=(ArrayList)ViewState["SelectedRowIndices"];
        bool flag=false;
        foreach (int i in SelecterdRowIndices)
        {
            if(i==Convert.ToInt32(ID))
            {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(!flag)
        {
            SelecterdRowIndices.Add(ID);
        }
    }  
    else
    {
         SelecterdRowIndices.Add(ID);
    }
    ViewState["SelectedRowIndices"] = SelecterdRowIndices;

}
```